# Can i change the scope location from global to website for ebay_price attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, scope

[image]

I have to change the scope of ebay price to website from global but there is not any option to change.

Suggest me it's urgent work.

[image]

Comment: I don't think M2E provides a configuration to change that.

I know Magento does under System > Configuration > Catalog > Price.

Could look into this configuration section as well as the M2E Pro configuration if you don't find a similar field for the ebay_price attribute ?

Comment: i have checked System > Configuration > Catalog > Price and there is catalog type set to website. But i didnt find for ebay_price attribute option to change scope global to website

Comment: First, M2E Pro doesn't add any attribute called 'ebay_price', it's some custom work done in your site previously, second, Price type attributes can't be set to a specific level in admin, they can only be created on the level specified here : System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Price : Catalog Price Scope, check if you have website level in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon you should check with M2E if they don't have an option for that.

If they don't, I think it is risky to change that setting as they is probably a good reason behind it.

If you really want to change it, a dirty hacky way of doing it is to edit the app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/attribute/js.phtml file

And comment the following line:

```
setRowVisibility('is_global', scopeVisibility);
```

You will have access to the Scope field, be able to edit it and save your ebay_price attribute.

Don't forget to comment the line back after your change.

Again,I don't recommend doing this, I suggest you contact M2E first and ask them what would be the good procedure in your case.